# How to type hint with walrus operator?

Tags: python, walrus-operator

I am trying to type hint a walrus operator expression, i.e.

`while (var: int := some_func()): ...`

How can I do this?

Answer (score 17):

It's not possible. From [PEP 572](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/)

> Inline type annotations are not supported:

You need to declare the variable before the `while` loop, and you can specify the type there.

```
var: int
while var := some_func():
    ...
```

Comment: Is the `= 0` necessary?   It seems like `var: int` would be enough.

Comment: If you don't initialize it with an integer, you need `var: Optional[int]` so it doesn't violate the type.

Comment: Interesting.  `var: int` doesn't actually create `var`, so it never has the value `None`. Why would the type be violated?

Comment: I was just going by what the PEP said. It suggested `var: Optional[int] = None`

Comment: I don't think the `Optional` hint is required; it's just the one used as an example. `var: int` alone should be fine, as long as `some_func` is guaranteed to return an `int`.

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe you can.

A variable can be annotated because the grammar rule for assignment is

```
assignment:
    | NAME ':' expression ['=' annotated_rhs ] 

    ...
```

Note that the type hint is explicit between the `:` following the name and the `=`.

An assignment expression, on the other hand, *only* provides for a name, no type hint, preceding the `:=`:

```
named_expression:
    | NAME ':=' ~ expression 
    | expression !':='
```

Comment: this seems like an oversight? I would expect that this operator would be implemented with proper typing

Comment: Python's grammar is intentionally restricted so that it can be parsed by an LL(1) parser. I'm fuzzy on the details (it's been a *long* time since I've studied parsers), but I think something like `if x: int := f(y):` can't be expressed with an LL(1) grammar; the lookahead needed to tell if the `:` following the `x` introduces a type hint or finishes the condition simply isn't available to an LL(1) parser. Python now uses a PEG parser, which I think is much more flexible, but `:=` predates the introduction of the new parser.

Comment: The walrus operator seems like an incomplete/flawed concept if it can't even be used with instance variables and type hints.